# Considerations on Recordtypes

Tags: governorlimits, record-type

Salesforce claims that there should not be more than 200 recordtypes in an org. It cites that this can be difficult for people to manage. Is this due to limitations they run into on Salesforce, or is this due to the nature of managing 200 different record types?

I have an application where the design may involve several record types in order to prevent the SOQL query limit on Parent-Child queries.

Thanks,

[Article on RecordTypes from SF](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.recordtypes_picklists_limitations.htm&type=5)

Comment: It's purely maintenance of that many record types over time. Can you elaborate on this a little bit? **involve record types in order to prevent the SOQL query limit on Parent-Child queries**

Comment: Thanks for the comment Mark. The plan was to have one master object and several child objects. But SOQL only allows for 20 parent child queries in a  single SOQL query. Second, Custom objects only allow 40 lookups. So the recordtypes seem the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Maintenance** in the main.
However Recordtypes are held in resident memory, and can be retrieved via Schema describe calls, making recordtype and high performing feature, but yes Salesforce would be wearing the overhead of recordtypes sitting in RAM, so I suppose it is a bit of both.

I think you might have another question that relates to best way forward for the architecture you wish to proceed with.

Recordtypes are like a subClass, they are great for extending your object, but they come with a lot more maintenance.

Comment: Thanks NZ Dev. I haven't considered any other options at this time. But with applications that have a lot of objects required for storing the data, it seems RecordTypes are the best way forward. I suppose you could also use unrelated objects, but I think that would get messy quickly on the Apex Side.

Comment: Another question I have, is will this significantly impact HEAP in working with these recordTypes in Apex?

Comment: re: Heap - no issue; recordtypeId is the only field added to the sobject